# I can't use mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 and mongoose-paginate-v2 in the same project

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

in a part of the project I need to use mongoose-paginate-v2 and it works perfect

[image]

the problem occurs when I try to implement mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 in another data model

[image]

because when I install it it warns me that in the implementation of the first library (mongoose-paginate-v2) there is no "paginate ()" function

[image]

Is there a way i can use both plugins?